# How to Convert Postgresql Boolean to MySQL Tinyint?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am trying to migrate a PostgreSQL table to a MySQL with all data, but I could not migrate because of two columns.
These columns are in the Postgresql table as boolean and values in these columns are TRUE or FALSE (it looks like a string). I created a boolean column in MySQL but it doesn't accept the TRUE/FALSE data. What should I use instead of boolean for these TRUE/FALSE values? I tried tinyint(4) but it doesn't work(I must migrate the data as it is TRUE or FALSE, not t/f or 1/0).

An example:

```
Postgresqltable( id bigserial not null, message_listening boolean, ....... ) 
Example record: (1, TRUE, .......)
```

Comment: Can you show us the generated sql or csv format with an example record?

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa
Postgresqltable(
id bigserial not null,
message_listening boolean
.......
)
Example row for postgresqltable:
(1, TRUE, ........)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrate them as `VARCHAR(255)`. Then, for each of those columns you want to convert to native MySQL `TINYINT(1)`:

- Create another column (e.g. `test`) of type `TINYINT(1)`
- Issue the command `UPDATE tbl SET test = IF( bool_col = 'TRUE', 1, 0 )`, where `bool_col` is the column you migrated from PostgreSQL which contains the Boolean string
- Drop the `bool_col` column
- Rename the `test` column to `bool_col` (or whatever you prefer)

Repeat the above steps for each column you want to convert.

Comment: Suppose the select used to generate the dump could incorporate that `IF`. Could be easier than working with temporary columns like that.

Comment: That would definitely be a better choice if it's possible to re-dump the data. But not an option if the data can't be dumped again.